# Cancel all notifications at specific time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uilocalnotification, nsdatecomponents

For my App I don't want notifications to go off in the weekends.
So my idea was to cancel all the notifications at a specific time on Fridays, I would like to do this by scheduling the task, just like I schedule notifications (`UILocalNotifications`)

So for example I have this code for my alarms:

```
NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [comps setHour:8];
    [comps setMinute:25];
    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDate *fireDate = [gregorian dateFromComponents:comps];

    UILocalNotification *alarm = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

    alarm.fireDate = fireDate;
    alarm.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
    alarm.soundName = @"sound.aiff";
    alarm.alertBody = @"Message..";
    alarm.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:alarm];
```

Is there a way to cancel all the notifications with the same method, or does Apple not allow this?

Answer (score 1):

You can cancel a local notification with:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:notification];
```

You would need to loop through all the local notifications and cancel them if they are on the weekend. Loop through them with:

```
NSArray *notifications = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];
[notifications enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UILocalNotification *notification, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){
    if (/* notification.fireDate is on weekend */) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:notification];
    }
}];
```

However you will have to ensure the app runs on a Friday to perform the code to remove the weekend notifications.

But, why not just not schedule ones that are on the weekend in the first place?

Comment: Sorry, might have not been clear enough I want the notifications to only display at weekdays, I can't schedule them day by day since Apple has a limit of 64 notifications as far as I know. The App will run on Fridays (It's an app for our business) I would like to use the cancelLocalNotification function to go off at a specific time, just like I schedule the notification at a specific time, is that possible?

Comment: Why don't you just have something in your app that checks every hour or so if there's notifications to cancel. I still don't quite see why you can't just not schedule notifications for weekends?

Answer (score 0):

You can cancel all the local notifications with the method

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
```

If you want to go through them, and maybe post the most important notifications, you could use `scheduledLocalNotifications`.